# Cant physically type in variable value text box when editing PATH environment variable

Tags: windows-8, environment-variables, path, window

I am quite lost with this and hope someone faces similar problem and fixed it. But it's as simple as not being able to type in the provided text box for changing variables values in the PATH.

I can delete what is in the box, but not add anything new. I have tried adding variables through `setx`, no luck. Even tried some GUI tools for managing this. Also no luck. I hope they are not the cause of the problem. They worked fine and I used both ways without any issues. But after one day, it just wouldn't work.

What is the solution to this? I cant post an image to give a bit of a visual assistance. But I hope I can fix this.

Comment: try to run cmd as admin and type this command in: `rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables` try to change the variables now

Comment: Same story. If I edit anything but "path" I can change, but path variables are locked.. Crazy